# How to host an ASP.NET application from within a ZIP archive using the Cassini web server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, clickonce, cassini

The root issue is that we have an ASP.Net application with a deep folder structure that we run within the Cassini web server and install on customer machines using a ClickOnce deployment. However, ClickOnce imposes limits on file path lengths which is starting to cause our deployment to fail. There are also a bunch of other issues with ClickOnce (e.g. handling of binaries in the web-app's bin folder) which we have solved via 'creative' means (i.e. hacky), as such we think a nice way to side step these ClickOnce issues is to deploy the ASP.NET app as a single zip archive. To Do that Cassini and ASP.NET would need to be able to the ZIP archive as a virtual file system.

One method might be to mount the zip archive in the file system (e.g. mapped to a new drive letter); The concern there is that some customer environments will likely prevent the application from mounting a new drive.

Ideally then we're looking for some means of representing a zip as a file system that we can point Cassini and ASP.NET to, but that isn't being done by the OS.

=== Update ===

Possible options:

- Unzip to a temp folder and point to that folder.
- MSDN article: [Virtualizing Access to Content: Serving Your Web Site from a ZIP File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479502.aspx)

Comment: I would recommend asking this over at SuperUser.com.  They would probably have better insight, and questions like this belong over there IMO.

Comment: *what I need is the ability to mount a zip in the file system* Global solution to a local problem. Just give your application the ability to read ZIP files.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Not really, I'm actually going to point the Cassini web server at this folder, so it's not my app code that is accessing the file directly. In fact ideally I wouldn't mount the files as this may work with the security model of some customers. Ideally I would create a virtual file system that the app can see, but the OS has no   involvement with.

Comment: @AdamPlocher See my comment to ta.speot.is. The root problem is an application development problem, on reflection I'm thining that mounting the files within the OS is just one possible solution and perhaps not the best one.

Comment: Why don't you write an `ashx` that serves up files from the zip? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228090(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If I understand correctly that would handle static content only. What I need is an entire web app to be hosted from within the zip.

Comment: Have completely reworded the question based on feedback so far. Thanks.